# RubyMine can't find RSpec specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, rubymine

I am just starting a project in RubyMine and am having trouble configuring RSpec. The problem is that it does not seem to be 'seeing' my tests, `0 files were loaded.`.
I am expecting the test to fail, I am just unsure as to why it is not running in the first place.
All the relevant gems have been installed and bundled correctly so far as I can tell and they are all included in the development section of my `Gemfile`.

The output from running RSpec, followed by my files:

```
/Users/richardcurteis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb
Testing started at 19:26 ...
Work directory: /Users/richardcurteis/Development/RubymineProjects/RevenantTech/spec
Loading files.... 
=========================================

0 files were loaded.
=========================================
Running tests...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`spec/controllers/welcome_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe WelcomeController do

  describe  do
    context 'User browses to home page' do
      it 'displays a welcome message' do
        visit '/welcome'
        expect(page).should have_content('Coming soon...')
      end
    end
  end

end
```

`spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end
```

`spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'rails/helper'

# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

`spec/helpers/welcome_spec_helper.rb`

```
#require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'
# Specs in this file have access to a helper object that includes
# the WelcomeHelper. For example:
#
# describe WelcomeHelper do
#   describe "string concat" do
#     it "concats two strings with spaces" do
#       expect(helper.concat_strings("this","that")).to eq("this that")
#     end
#   end
# end
#RSpec.describe WelcomeHelper, type: :helper do
#  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
#end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like RubyMine is running RSpec in the spec directory. By default, RSpec looks in a subdirectory, named spec, of the directory it's run in. RubyMine seems to be misconfigured. Either something is wrong with that particular run/debug configuration or the RubyMine project thinks that the spec directory (rather than the directory above it) is the project root.

You can confirm that RSpec itself is OK on the command line by `cd`ing to the root of your project and running `bin/rspec`.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case. Running from the command line seems to have sorted the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine:

- Step 1 : In the RubyMine menu bar click on "Run".
- Step 2 : Select "edit configurations".
- Step 3 : Add a new configuration by clicking `[+]`.
- Step 4 : Verify the Feature folder and add the folder path up to features. For example; `C:\Ruby_Projects\project\features`.
- Step 5 : Also change working directory.

Answer (score 0):

For me, even though the option disappeared for the root of my project, I could still right click on a sub folder, and choose `Run all specs in...` to run all specs.

Answer (score 0):

This line is likely causing the problem:

```rb
  describe  do
```

Change to `describe 'whatever' do` and it may work.

RubyMine apparently traps over `describe` or `context` calls without description.